# Restricted access to perform write actions for Twitter app

Tags: ios, twitter, sharing

I have an app through which user can share on twitter. Everything was going great few days ago but suddenly, I started receiving permission errors. I checked my permissions but surprisingly, I got this:

[image]

Permissions are also set as read write but still I am getting error on sharing.

I don't know what is wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that your app could have been used maliciously? Have you asked Twitter to see why you've been suspended?

Comment: My app is approved by App Store and has been used for more than 6 months. It was working fine

Comment: The app store has nothing to do with it.  Twitter have suspended you - that means only they can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to a number of developers - see https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/473547632669782016

> If your application lost write access this week-end and you believe this is an error, please fill https://t.co/jUQPuVHhyo (3rd option).